# Requests Proxy not Working

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently writing a scraper for testing want to access the site with a different IP, I have found a lot of information about using a proxy and tried this several times, however when I access a site that shows the IP used in the request, it shows the IP of my computer.

I am using a free Proxy I found online.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
proxy = {'SOCKS5': '24.145.195.60:27595'}
response = requests.get('http://www.whatsmyip.de/', proxies=proxy)
print response
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the proxy you are using? mind posting a link.. and you need to use a html parser like bs4 to actually print the ip

Comment: I found the proxy on this website: http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/search-1305361 and thought that the requests libary sends the request to that server, and returns if from it. I am probably getting the concept a bit wrong, but couldnt find more info on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a proxy for the `HTTP` and or a `HTTPS` protocol. I'm not sure if `requests` works with `SOCKS` protocol yet

This works for me.

```
import requests
import bs4

proxy = {"http": "115.227.195.213"}
response = requests.get('http://www.whatsmyip.de/', proxies=proxy)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

print soup.h3.text
```

Note: It uses the [bs4 module](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to print the ip and I used a proxy server that is `HTTP` compatible

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately the site still receives my real IP address. Any other suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: @user3655289 use a HTTP server it should fix your issue, use a different HTTP server as the HTTP server in answer in my answer is out of date

Comment: Awesome! It worked now, and is all good! Thank you good sir. One last question - When do I use a http and when do I use a https proxy?

Comment: @user3655289 I'm not sure about that one BTW you might be in luck if you ask [here](http://superuser.com/)