# Python 'requests' with proxy not working / leaking IP?

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, web-scraping, lxml, python-requests

(Strongly) related to: [Requests Proxy not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190324/requests-proxy-not-working)
I'm new to python so apologies for blunders I might've made.

Whatever proxy I choose, whenever I check my IP on http://www.whatismyproxy.com/ it displays my real IP and a "There may be a proxy"-note. I've tried dozens of different proxies from different sources...always declared as "elite". So apparently, the issue is with my code. Here goes nothing:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
base_url = 'http://www.whatismyproxy.com/'

def pagefetch(url):
    httpproxy = "http://111.13.109.51"
    proxydict = {
                "http_proxy": httpproxy
                }

    page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxydict)
    return page

def scrape1(base_url):
    page = pagefetch(base_url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    head1 = tree.xpath('//p[@class="h1"]/text()')
    return head1

txt1 = scrape1(base_url)
print txt1
```

This is a simplified version of a scraper I'm currently working on, thus its slightly clunky.
To clarify, I have no issues connecting to the proxy(s).
Thanks in advance =) I'm using ubuntu 14.04 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `proxydict` is wrong. It should be

```
proxydict = {
    'http': httpproxy
}
```

If instead you wanted to specify your proxy as a parameter to your script, you would do this:

```
http_proxy='http://111.13.109.51' python my_script.py
```

Comment: ...oh, wow. Thats just...embarassing. Who the hell told me to set it up this way!? Damn you internetz!
Thank you...alot! =)
Needless to say, this worked for me.

Comment: It's easy to confuse them. I've done so a couple times at least and I'm a core developer on requests =P